# Java arrays printing out weird numbers and text

Tags: java, arrays, text, numbers

I'm new to programming. I'm sure the answer for this question is out there, but I have no idea what to search for.

Ok, I'll go right to it.

Here's my code:

```
int[] arr;
arr = new int[5];

arr[0] = 20;
arr[1] = 50;
arr[2] = 40;
arr[3] = 60;
arr[4] = 100;

System.out.println(arr);
```

This compiles and works fine. It's just the output from CMD that I'm dizzy about.

This is the output: `[I@3e25a5`.

I want the output to represent the exact same numbers from the list (`arr`) instead. How do I make that happen?

Comment: @Duncan Jones Funny that you marked this post as a duplicate when it came like 4 years before the other post... I understand that the linked post is a tutorial like post, though.

Comment: @LAD Yes, it's a bit odd. But it's a common practice here - you can close older questions as duplicates if there is a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 28):

Every object has a `toString()` method, and the default method is to display the object's class name representation, then `@` followed by its hashcode. So what you're seeing is the default `toString()` representation of an `int` array. To print the data in the array, you can use:

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Or, you can loop through the array with a `for` loop as others have posted in this thread.

Answer (score 8):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

The current output is `classtype@hashcode`.

**Incase you need to print arrays with more than one dimension use:**

```
Arrays.deepToString(arr);
```

Also remember [to override `toString()`](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55) method for user-defined classes so that you get a representation of the objet as you choose and not the default represention which is `classtype@hashcode`

Answer (score 5):

It's the default string representation of array (the weird text).

You'll just have to loop through it:

```
for(int i : arr){
System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To print the values use.

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
   System.out.println(arr[i]);
```

Comment: not a memory address. Class Name + "@" + hashcode.

Comment: You are right. I'll edit that

Comment: Well, it kind of is a memory address in many if not most situations. The Object API states that the result of toString is: getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode()) and the API further states that in order for hashCode to try to return as unique a number as possible: This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.  So if hashCode and toString haven't been overridden, you'll see an internal address.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
{
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

That "weird number" is the reference for the array you printed out.  It's the default behavior built into the java.lang.Object toString() method.

You should override it in your own objects if seeing the reference isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

It prints it's .toString() method you should print each element

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(arr[i]);
}

or

for(Integer i : arr) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

BTW You can write

```
int[] arr = { 20, 40, 60, 40, 60, 100 };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

or even

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(new int[] { 20, 40, 60, 40, 60, 100 }));
```

or

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(20, 40, 60, 40, 60, 100));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
{
  System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why the loop if you are always printing arr[] ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Arrays.toString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(double%5B%5D)) and [PrintStream.printf(String format, Object... args)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

```
System.out.printf("%s%n", Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `printf` over `println` here, as existing answers have

Answer (score -3):

You printed the reference and not the values at the reference... One day it will all become clear with C.

Comment: Not really, no. He printed what `.toString()` returns, and `.toString` on arrays returns a string of the form `"[<element-type-code>@<hashCode>"`.