# Java Array Computing

Tags: java, arrays

```
int n = 10;
double[] x = {2.5,0.5,2.2,1.9,3.1,2.3,2,1,1.5,1.1};
double[] y = {2.4,0.7,2.9,2.2,3.0,2.7,1.6,1.1,1.6,0.9};

double sumx = 0.0, sumy = 0.0, sumx2 = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sumx += x[i];
    sumy += y[i];
}

double xbar = sumx / n;
double ybar = sumy / n;
```

I have 2 results for mean values of x and y now I want to create a new array but this new array should include for example:

```
double[] x1 =[2.5-xbar,0.5-xbar,.....];
double[] x2 =[2.4-ybar,0.7-ybar,.....];
```

I want to get those arrays by using any loop and i tried to build but couldn't success.
My codes:

```
double[] xadj = new double[10],yadj = new double[10];
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
    xadj[i]+=x[i]-xbar;
    yadj[i]+=y[i]-ybar;
}

System.out.println(xadj);
System.out.println(yadj);
```

**[OUTPUT]:**

```
[D@17dfafd1
[D@5e8fce95
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: If you want to print the content of your array, use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xadj))`.

Comment: Or to print - iterate over the array and print each lament out separately

Comment: Also don't use `n` , you can use `array.length`

Comment: problem solved by System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xadj)); thx. ZouZou,if you enter answer I will accept it as a true answer

Comment: @user3138900 Altough zouzou comment is correct, you have another issues i point in my answer that you should read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Arrays.toString(double[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28double%5B%5D%29)

> Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified
>   array. The string representation consists of a list of the array's
>   elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are
>   separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space).
>   Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(double).
>   Returns "null" if a is null.

But you have some rare things in your code. Use `array.length` instead of hardcoded n. Also you don't have to `+=` only assign with `=`

```
double[] xadj = new double[10],yadj = new double[10];
        for(int i=0;i< x.length ;i++){
            xadj[i]=x[i]-xbar;
            yadj[i]=y[i]-ybar;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xadj));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xadj));
```

What you are seeing with this

> [D@17dfafd1

array toString() on a double array prints the type of the array ([D) followed by its hashCode.

Answer (score 1):

> System.out.println(xadj);
>
> System.out.println(yadj);

You are printing reference to array and hence the output.

Try iterating over array and print each element or use `Arrays.toString()` to print

Every object has a `toString()` method, and the default method is to display the object's class name representation, then "@" followed by its **hashcode**. So what you're seeing is the default `toString()` representation of an array.

Refer [1] [Java arrays printing out weird numbers, and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479683/java-arrays-printing-out-weird-numbers-and-text)

Answer (score 1):

Your "results" are the *memory addresses* of the `xadj` and `yadj` objects in memory because you simply printed out the reference to the object and not each of the cells within that object. Easiest beginner's way to do this is by using another `for` loop to print the results.

Instead of:

```
System.out.println(xadj);
System.out.println(yadj);
```

Try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println(xadj[i]);
    System.out.println(yadj[i]);
}
```