# Trying to create an array in Java. What did I just do?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to Java but not new to programming. I ran the following code in Eclipse:

```
int[] intArray = new int[5];
System.out.println(intArray);
```

and received the following output:

```
[I@17f7be7b
```

I'm sure StackOverflow already contains the correct way to create an array in Java. What I'd like to know is: what *did* I do?

---

**Edit:** Sorry... The link above my post isn't a duplicate question, and it doesn't answer my question. TylerAndFriends' link is closer, but I was hoping for an explanation of exactly what I printed. Tyler's linked thread says `"the default method is to display the object's class name representation, then "@" followed by its hashcode"`. Can someone elaborate?

Comment: Look into array types and the inherited `Object#toString()` method.

Comment: Check this out:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/4479683/2282538

Comment: Use `Arrays.toString();`

Comment: Also, ask yourself how and why Java would print the elements of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
       for (int i : intArray) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
```