# String to String Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, string, syntax

I have a big problem. I have just try to search a solution, but i don't have find any solution. i have this code

```
public static String getString() throws IOException {

    String content = null;
    File folder = new File("C:\\Soluzioni.txt");

    content = FileUtils.readFileToString(folder) + "\n";
    String remainingString = content.substring(content.indexOf("["),
            content.lastIndexOf("]") + 1);
    System.out.println(remainingString);
    return remainingString;

}
```

And this is ok. (For clarity)

```
OUTPUT :[40,-13,-6,-7,-4] [28,-40,45,-29,37] [-43,19,-24,-9,-45] [26,-41,-28,-16,44]
```

My problem is now:

```
public static String[] arg() throws IOException {
    String[] strArray = { getString() };
    System.out.println(strArray);
    return strArray;
}
```

when i print strArray, i have an error (ECLIPSE show me this: [Ljava.lang.String;@796686c8). I would need my string (remainingString) to become an array of strings(strArray), but that maintained the same format, that is, it was always 
`OUTPUT :[40,-13,-6,-7,-4] [28,-40,45,-29,37] [-43,19,-24,-9,-45] [26,-41,-28,-16,44]`
but with array format. Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to loop through the array and print the indivudual elements.

Comment: What's wrong with `Arrays.toString`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java arrays printing out weird numbers, and text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479683/java-arrays-printing-out-weird-numbers-and-text)

Answer (score 6):

Arrays are objects too in Java, but they don't override [`Object`'s `toString()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()), which is responsible for the output: `[Ljava.lang.String;@796686c8`

> In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

Use [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) to generate the expected array output:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
```

Comment: yes,thank you. But later I wanted to pass my array to a different method, in particular, should do so as?. about the code in up, i should use string[] arg() in this method (any solution)?                                                                                                     public static void parseClauses(List<Clausola> F, String[] arg, int N) {

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `Arrays.toString()` method which returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.

Change your system out to `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));`

`System.out.println(strArray);` will print the Object toString value `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

That's why you are getting `[Ljava.lang.String;@796686c8)`.

Please refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html for more information.