# toCharArray() method showing error

Tags: java, error-handling, syntax-error

I coded a sample Java program:

```
String str="JAVA is awesome";
char[] ch=str.toCharArray();
System.out.println("The value of ch is : " + ch);
```

It is showing an unexpected result with some random ascii value... What is the problem?

Comment: It's probably printing the address of the `ch` object. What do you expect it to print?

Comment: What you're seeing will look something like `[C@48a2e6`. This is a composition of the class of `ch` (which is `[C`, or character array), followed by the @ symbol and the hexadecimal string representation of the array's hash code.

Comment: FYI: In this example alone, you don't need to instantiate ch as a new char[n], and therefore you don't need n either.  char[] ch = str.toCharArray();  is fine :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java arrays printing out weird numbers, and text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479683/java-arrays-printing-out-weird-numbers-and-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need this step `char ch[]=new char[n];`

As javadoc says [String#toCharArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray())- returns a newly allocated character array whose length is the length of this string and whose contents are initialized to contain the character sequence represented by this string.

And in this line `System.out.println("The value of ch is : " + ch);`

Just returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object.

So this few lines below should do what you want to achieve

```
String str="JAVA is awesome";
char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(ch));
```

Where [Arrays.toString(char[] ch)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(char[])) - Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array. The string representation consists of a list of the array's elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space).

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
System.out.println("The value of ch is : " + ch);
```

Will print out

```
The value of ch is : //And the hash code of your array, which is just an object in Java
```

If you want meaningful data, use the `Arrays.toString()` overloaded method...

```
System.out.println("The value of ch is : " + Arrays.toString(ch));
```

Take a look at the Javadocs for the [Array.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(char[])) method to see when it may be useful in your case.

Comment: yeah.. but when i use Arrays.string error comes : 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method toString() in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (char[])

 at spidy.test.main(test.java:15)

Comment: I hope you mean `Arrays.toString(ch)`.. And what error comes? Compilation or runtime? Give some information...

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
System.out.println("The value of ch is : " + ch);
```

is equivalent to this

```
System.out.println("The value of ch is : " + ch.toString());
```

As `ch` is an array object it inherits `toString()` method from [Object.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29). This returns *a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object*.

Try to use one of these for the output you need:

```
System.out.println("The value of ch is : " + new String(ch)); //prints ch array as String
System.out.println("The value of ch is : " + String.valueOf(ch)); //prints ch array as String
System.out.println("The value of ch is : " + Arrays.toString(ch)); //prints every letter separately
```

Comment: @RushabhWadkar Glad I could help. If you find the answer helpful, and it solves your problem you can always accept it.