# Printing value at array index returns hashcode

Tags: java, arrays, int, hashcode

Just playing around with displaying values in a two dimensional array and noticed my code prints some `hashcodes` and then the values. But I am not printing the array object itself (as done in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479683/java-arrays-printing-out-weird-numbers-and-text)) or at least explicitly calling the `toString` or `hashcode` method of the array object. Instead, I'm directly accessing and printing the values in the array using `arrayObj[i]` and `arrayObj[i][j]`.

Here's my code:

```
class PrintTwoDimArray {
    public int [][] createArray () {
        int counter = 0;
        int[][] intArray = new int [2][4];
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < intArray[i].length; j++) {
                intArray[i][j] = ++counter;
            }
        }
        return intArray;
    }
    public void printArray ( int [][] arrayObj ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayObj.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arrayObj[i] + " ");
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayObj[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(arrayObj[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

class TestPrintTwoDimArray {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    
    PrintTwoDimArray twoDim = new PrintTwoDimArray();
    int [][] multiArray = new int [2][4];
    multiArray = twoDim.createArray();
    twoDim.printArray(multiArray);
    }
}
```

My output is as follows:

[image]

It seems that my code is somehow calling the `toString` or `hashcode` method of the array. Thoughts? How can I modify to print just the values?

**javac and java version 1.8.0**

Comment: this string is redundant: System.out.print(arrayObj[i] + " ");

Comment: @nikis I used the empty string to create a space between the values.

Comment: @sedeh: This is not the hash code: it's the address in the memory where your object is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A two dimensional array is an array of arrays. The array you create (`int[2][4]`) looks like this

```
[ 0 ] -> [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 1 ] -> [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
```

So when you only access the first dimension you will get the array that holds the second dimension.

```
int[][] arr = createArray();
System.out.println(arr[0]);
```

will output something like

```
[I@1db9742
```

To print an array's values you can use `Arrays.toString(arr)`. In this case you can omit the inner loop, because `Arrays.toString()` will do it for you.

```
 public void printArray ( int [][] arrayObj ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayObj.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayObj[i]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The hash values come from your first System.print sentence.

System.out.print(arrayObj[i] + " ");

With this sentence you are printing an Object (an array) and therefore Java is invoking the default toString method.

Answer (score 0):

When you print

```
arrayObj[i]
```

you get the default `Object` `toString()` from an array. You could use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29) to make that a `String` like

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayObj[i]));
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Arrays.deepToString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object[]%29) to print your multi-dimensional array without a loop

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayObj));
```

**Edit**

You could use formatted output to build your table.

```
public static void printArray(int[][] arrayObj) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayObj.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%03d: ", i + 1);
        for (int val : arrayObj[i]) {
            System.out.printf("% 4d ", val);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] table = { { 3, 1, 2 }, { 5, 1, 4 }, { 100, 200, 300 } };
    printArray(table);
}
```

Output is

```
001:    3    1    2 
002:    5    1    4 
003:  100  200  300
```

Comment: `deepToString` works sleek and I've noted it. In this scenario though, I like to print the values as a grid. Not sure how to implement `Arrays.toString(int[])` here bcos the second print statement has double int values. Something like this won't work: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayObj[i][j]))`. Further thoughts?

Comment: @sedeh Write your own `toString(int[])` that builds a `String` with a `StringBuilder` and format it how you like. Also, your "double int values" is a single `int` value at it's array position of `i,j`.