# Java String getBytes nondetermism

Tags: java, string, serialization

I cannot figure out why calling getBytes() twice on a String returns two byte arrays that are not equal():

```
final String aString = "hello world";
System.out.println(aString.getBytes());
System.out.println(aString.getBytes());
System.out.println(aString.getBytes());
```

Prints:

```
[B@59887d29
[B@fd13cab
[B@71e606a9
```

E.g. the following assertion always fails:

```
Assert.assertEquals(aString.getBytes(), aString.getBytes());
```

From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()), I wasn't expecting any nondeterminism! What am I missing?

When converting back to String, the result is the expected one, so my best guess is some uninitialized padding bit?

I.e. the following assertion always passes:

```
Assert.assertEquals(new String(aString.getBytes()), new String(aString.getBytes()));
```

Comment: Combination of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479683/java-arrays-printing-out-weird-numbers-and-text and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Assert#assertEquals(Object, Object)`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) uses `Object#equals(Object)` to compare its arguments, but array types don't override that method. So two array instances will always be different.

Use [`Assert#assertArrayEquals(byte[], byte[])`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertArrayEquals(byte[],%20byte[])) to compare arrays of type `byte`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `getBytes()` returns a `byte[]`, and arrays are `Object`s in Java.  However, these array objects don't override [`Object`'s `toString()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--), which is responsible for the output you see.

> In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

The output includes the hash code, which is different for every object, even if the contents are the same.

Use [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-byte:A-) to obtain a `String` with the contents of the array, e.g.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aString.getBytes()));
```

3 times.  New output:

```
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains the different output of println, but why is assertEqual returning false?

Comment: While my answer explains the string output, Sotirios's answer explains why better, with the solution included.