# Converting String to Sha-256 Hash

Tags: java, arrays, string, hash, sha

I want to convert a String to a SHA-256 Hash. I am using this code:

```
String text = "YOLO";
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] hash = digest.digest(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
System.out.println(hash.toString());
```

The problem is, when I start the program, it prints

> [B@28d93b30

Why is this, and how can solve this?

Thanks in advance,

Fihdi

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java arrays printing out weird numbers, and text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479683/java-arrays-printing-out-weird-numbers-and-text)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, you're using the default *toString()* method which simply outputs the class name and hashcode

If you want a hex print out of the contents of the byte array try...
[Hex.encodeHexString(byte[] data)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#encodeHexString(byte[])) from Apache Commons.

Also [How to convert a byte array to a hex string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java) has some examples for doing this without a library.

Answer (score 1):

To print the bytes as hex (instead of that result, explained in [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)), simply run:

```
System.out.println((new HexBinaryAdapter()).marshal(hash));
```

Answer (score 0):

In JAVA, arrays do not override `Object.toString()`. Therefore, `hash.toString()` does not return a representation of the contents of the array, but rather a representation of the array itself. Apparently, this representation of an array is not very useful. The d[efault `toString()` implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) returns

```
 getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this type of issue and then solve in this way.

```
String text = "YOLO";
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] hash = digest.digest(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hash);        
System.out.println(encoded.toLowerCase());
```