# Problems working with Password Hashing using salt

Tags: java, mysql, hash, salt

It's my first time dealing with Password hashing in a web application.
I used https://www.codeproject.com/articles/704865/salted-password-hashing-doing-it-right for theory and copied a sample from https://github.com/defuse/password-hashing.
In my understanding, the salt should be unique for every account. So my question would be:

why is the salt generated in this method:

```
 public static String createHash(char[] password)
    throws CannotPerformOperationException
{
    // Generate a random salt
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_BYTE_SIZE];
    random.nextBytes(salt);

    // Hash the password
    byte[] hash = pbkdf2(password, salt, PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, HASH_BYTE_SIZE);
    int hashSize = hash.length;

    // format: algorithm:iterations:hashSize:salt:hash
    String parts = "sha1:" +
        PBKDF2_ITERATIONS +
        ":" + hashSize +
        ":" +
        toBase64(salt) +
        ":" +
        toBase64(hash);
    return parts;
}
```

What I would Need is a function which stores a hashed password and the used salt from a database. How can I retrieve the used salt from here?

```
System.out.println(salt);
```

Always writes

```
[B@29453f44
```

In the console. Why is this the case? And what data type would I Need to store the salt in the mysql database? Or do I have the wrong Approach?

Comment: You're asking multiple questions here, which is never a good idea on SO. The output is due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687160

Comment: I don't quite understand your first questions. The salt is generated as a random salt for each new user. Which makes it pretty unique. You could also use something else as salt, like the `ID` for the user in the DB, but this is still unique. And then you concatenate it to `parts` with the `hash`, `hashSize` etc. Why do you need to retrieve it here? When you later want to authenticate a given password, since you know all the lengths and order of `parts` you can retrieve the `salt` part from `parts` and hash the given password to verify its authenticity

Comment: You only store `parts` in your database as text `varchar` or `char`. You don't separate the salt and store it separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your questions correctly then:

> In my understanding, the salt should be unique for every account.

```
byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_BYTE_SIZE];
random.nextBytes(salt);
```

Generates a random salt, which makes it unique. 
You could also use use the `ID` for the user from the database or something else unique, but a randomly generated salt is also unique, since afterall, for each new user a new salt is randomly generated.

This `salt` is then in your code concatenated together with the `hash`, the `hashSize`, the algorithm and the number of `iterations` into `parts`

```
 // format: algorithm:iterations:hashSize:salt:hash
String parts = "sha1:" +
    PBKDF2_ITERATIONS +
    ":" + hashSize +
    ":" +
    toBase64(salt) +
    ":" +
    toBase64(hash);
return parts;
```

Often you know the lengths (byte size) of the different parts in `parts` and can thus extract the part you need. In your case you have even added a `:` as a separator which makes it even simpler to extract the part you are interested in.

> And what data type would I Need to store the salt in the mysql database?

Once you have gotten your `parts`, this is what you save in the database as text (`varchar` or `char`). You do not separate it and store `salt` separately. Just mash it all in together.

When a user then wants to sign in, they provide a password. Now you fetch `parts` for the user from the database, you extract the `salt`, number of `iterations` and so on from `parts`, since afterall, you know exactly how it is concatenated. Then you use that information to hash the inputted password from the user again. Now you compare the new hash, with the old hash. If they are the same, well, then the user gave the correct password, if not, he didn't.

> Always writes `[B@29453f44` In the console.

As @JonSkeet said, the answer is given in [Converting String to Sha-256 Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687160/converting-string-to-sha-256-hash)