# Java NIO server receives random string

Tags: java, buffer, nio

I am trying to create a messaging system,but first I would like the code to be able to do the following:

1. Client sends a string

   2. Server receives the string and echos it back to the client that sent it

For some reason this is what happens

```
Client : Sent String : meow
Server : Received : [B@5ef4b65d
Client : Received : [B@5ef4b65d
```

what does **[B@5ef4b65d** mean? Does it mean that the client is not able to send meow to server and the server just generates some random string? I am not able to figure out what going on.
I have pasted my code, but if someone can let me know what this means, I can probably take it from there.

```
ClientCore:

    public void send(byte[] data, ResponseHandler handler) throws IOException {
        byte[] rspData = "ERROR".getBytes(); 

        try {

            ByteBuffer sendStr = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
            ByteBuffer rcv = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(BUFFER_SIZE);

            channel.write(sendStr).get();
            // By adding .get(), this becomes a blocking call.
            int numRead = channel.read(rcv).get();

            rcv.flip();

            String rspStr = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(rcv).toString();
            //String dummyresp = ByteBuffer.wrap(rcv).getString();
            rspData = rspStr.getBytes();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }

        handler.handleResponse(rspData);
    }

}
```

ResponseHandler:

```
public class ResponseHandler {
    private byte[] rsp = null;

    public synchronized boolean handleResponse(byte[] rsp) {
        this.rsp = rsp;
        this.notify();
        return true;
    }

    public synchronized byte[] waitForResponse() {
        while (this.rsp == null) {
            try {
                this.wait();
                // interrupt thread
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //String response = new String(this.rsp);
        return this.rsp;
    }
}
```

Server :

```
    public void read(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {



        SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

        // Clear out our read buffer so it's ready for new data
        this.readBuffer.clear();

        // Attempt to read off the channel
        int numRead;
        try {
            numRead = socketChannel.read(this.readBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // The remote forcibly closed the connection, cancel
            // the selection key and close the channel.
            key.cancel();
            socketChannel.close();
            return;
        }
        // numread is the number of bytes in the buffer
        if (numRead == -1) {
            // Remote entity shut the socket down cleanly. Do the
            // same from our end and cancel the channel.
            key.channel().close();
            key.cancel();
            return;
        }

        // Hand the data off to the Message Worker
        System.out.println(readBuffer.array());
        messageWorkerPool.execute(new MessageWorker(this, socketChannel,this.readBuffer.array(), numRead, 0));

    }

    public void write(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {

        SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

        synchronized (this.pendingData) {
            List<ByteBuffer> queue = this.pendingData.get(socketChannel);

            // Write until there's not more data ...
            while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                ByteBuffer buf = (ByteBuffer) queue.get(0);
                socketChannel.write(buf);
                if (buf.remaining() > 0) {
                    // ... or the socket's buffer fills up
                    break;
                }
                queue.remove(0);
            }

            if (queue.isEmpty()) {
                // We wrote away all data, so we're no longer interested
                // in writing on this socket. Switch back to waiting for
                // data.
                key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
            }
        }



    }

    public void send(SocketChannel socket, byte[] data) {
        synchronized (this.pendingChanges) {
            // Indicate we want the interest ops set changed


            long changeQueueArrivalTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            this.pendingChanges.add(new ChangeRequest(socket,
                    ChangeRequest.CHANGEOPS, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE,
                    changeQueueArrivalTime));
            // And queue the data we want written
            synchronized (this.pendingData) {
                List<ByteBuffer> queue = this.pendingData.get(socket);
                if (queue == null) {
                    queue = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();
                    this.pendingData.put(socket, queue);
                }
                queue.add(ByteBuffer.wrap(data));
            }
        }

        // Finally, wake up our selecting thread so it can make the required
        // changes
        this.selector.wakeup();
    }
```

From its main I call

```
ExecutorService servicePool = Executors
            .newFixedThreadPool(2);
    servicePool.execute(new MessageServer(servicePool,"localhost", 4444, 200));
```

and the worker :

```
public class MessageWorker implements Runnable {
    MessageServer server;
    SocketChannel socketchannel;

    int bufferlength;
    int begin_wait_worker;
    ServerDataEvent dataevent;
    String end;

    // will add pgpooling soon
    public MessageWorker(MessageServer server,SocketChannel sc, byte[] bs,int bufferlength, int start_wait_for_begin){
        end = "???";
        this.server = server;
        this.socketchannel = sc;

        this.bufferlength = bufferlength;
        this.begin_wait_worker =start_wait_for_begin; //just the time when the server wait for worker to start working on the read request
        byte[] dataCopy = new byte[bufferlength];
        System.arraycopy(bs, 0, dataCopy, 0, this.bufferlength);
        // used to send easily
        this.dataevent = new ServerDataEvent(this.server,this.socketchannel,dataCopy);
    }

    public void run(){

        String request = dataevent.data.toString();
        String response = String.format(request, end); // all repsonse request end with ???

        // get request split conveniently
        //Map< MapParameters, String> commandparameters = MessageDecoder.decodeCommandToMap(request) ;
        }

        this.dataevent.server.send(dataevent.socket, response.getBytes());

        }
        }
```

**EDIT :** I tried converting to a string using the answer marked, I still get the same thing.

Comment: I already tried converting it to string,I still get the same thing, could you possible show how its done?

Comment: It's not done by calling `toString` on a `byte[]` which I assume is what `data` is. See the linked post.

Comment: Here's why you have that output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479683/java-arrays-printing-out-weird-numbers-and-text

Comment: I understand now that I am not formatting it right, but I dont understand from these answers how I can get the right output

Comment: Use the `String` constructor that accepts a `byte[]`.

Comment: I did String res = new String(handler.waitforresponse()); I get the same thing!

Comment: I don't know what `handleresponse` is. Either it returns a `String` that contains the content you see, or it contains a `byte[]` whose value interpreted as a `String` is what you see. If you have a `byte[]` and you want to interpret its contents as a `String`, use the `String` constructor which accepts a `byte[]`.

Comment: That's a heck load of code, maybe you should isolate it. Secondly, that's when you are trying to toString a byte[], you get such stuff.

Comment: reponse handler returns a byte[] array, I did what you said and I dont understand why this happens,which is why I posted the question. I did not get my answer from the one you marked as duplicate.

Comment: @WeareBorg I tried with without tostring, I tried string constructor and I still get the same thing. May be I am misinterpreting what I shud do.

Comment: Meow, you should put less code...start with that.

Comment: Is your server echoing back what your client is sending? If you do the decoding wrong on the server, the echo back to client will also be wrong. Make sure it's correct in all places.

Comment: after I send data to the server, as you see I immediately printout what i get,what I concluded is that those odd symbols r what is received by the server itself,hence I ask for help, because I cannot locate the error.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I found the error, basically when I do message.getBytes() that gets sent to the server, the server sends the message.getBytes() back, but after that whatever I seem to do,I cannot get back my original String.

Comment: On what seems to be the server, you're doing `System.out.println(readBuffer.array());`. `println` internally invokes `toString` on the argument. That's not how you convert a `byte[]` to a `String`. I don't know what `ServerDataEvent` is, but you're probably doing the same thing then sending it to the client.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Your right! I was calling .toString() in the worker of the server, thank you!!!!