# How do I properly display my output in this instance?

Tags: java, string, output

So, I'm new to Java, and am doing an exercise to hone my skills. I'm trying to make a method that takes a string and returns to the user how many of what vowel the string has. This is what I have so far

```
    static int[] vowelCount(String english)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int e = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int o = 0;
        int u = 0;

        int[] counter = {a, e, i, o, u};

        for (int itt = 0; itt < english.length(); itt++)
        {
            if( english.charAt(itt) == 'a')a++;
            if( english.charAt(itt) == 'e')e++;
            if( english.charAt(itt) == 'i')i++;
            if( english.charAt(itt) == 'o')o++;
            if( english.charAt(itt) == 'u')u++;

        }

        return counter;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print(vowelCount("Java rocks!"));

    }
```

In this instance, I want my output to be {2,0,0,1,0}, but what I get is 
"[I@15db9742"

Comment: Because printing the array itself gives you its hashcode in Java. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479683/java-arrays-printing-out-weird-numbers-and-text).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can use `Arrays.toString()` to print out a visual representation of the array `counter`.

Secondly it would make more sense to store the position of the vowel in the array like below as currently you are not modifying the array at all i.e. `counter` looks like `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(vowelCount("Java rocks!")));
  }

  public static int[] vowelCount(String english) {
    //representing the position in the counter array
    int a = 0; 
    int e = 1; 
    int i = 2;
    int o = 3;
    int u = 4;

    int[] counter = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; 

    for (int itt = 0; itt < english.length(); itt++) {
      if( english.charAt(itt) == 'a') counter[a]++;
      if( english.charAt(itt) == 'e') counter[e]++;
      if( english.charAt(itt) == 'i') counter[i]++;
      if( english.charAt(itt) == 'o') counter[o]++;
      if( english.charAt(itt) == 'u') counter[u]++;
    }
    return counter;
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/HBxj/0)