# So I'm trying to make a code where you make an array with inputs and the outputs aren't quite right?

Tags: java, arrays

Ok so this is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Bubble {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String prefix;
        int arr[];
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What size would you like your array to be?");
        int arrSize = reader.nextInt();
        arr = new int[arrSize];
        for(int i = 1; i==arrSize; i++) {
            if((i % 10)==1 && i != 11) {
                prefix = "st";
            }else if((i % 10)==2 && i != 12) {
                prefix = "nd";
            }else if((i % 10)==3 && i != 13) {
                prefix = "rd";
            }else{
                prefix = "th";
            }

            System.out.println("What would you like the"+ i + prefix +"number in the array to be?");
            int arrNum = reader.nextInt();

        }
        System.out.println(arr);
    }

}
```

Now when I press run I get this:

What size would you like your array to be?

Then I put in an integer, say 3, then I get this:

[I@55f96302

It stays the same no matter what integer i use.

Comment: "It stays the same no matter what integer I use." That's because you are not printing an integer. You are printing an array of integers. There's lots more issues with your code - your `for` loop uses wrong indexes, and an incorrect continuation condition. You need to fix them before debugging this problem.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: you are printing the address in memory and not the values in your array

Comment: @G2M It is not an 'address in memory', it is the default `toString()` of an object, which contains the identity hashcode (which in theory might be derived from a memory address, but usually isn't).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel duely noted :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Arrays.toString()`.  Here's [a great writeup](http://javadevnotes.com/java-print-array-examples) of exactly the issue you're running into. By writing `System.out.println(arr);` you're printing a default string representation of your array. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4479703/3927977).

As far as I could understand, you're trying to allow a user to create an array with `arrSize` and after this allow him to put values inside the array. However, your code has some issues:

1 - Your condition in your for loop is never verified for `arrSize != 1`.

2 - To save the values inside the defined array you should assign the value read from scanner `arrNum` to the array position `i-1` (in order to avoid an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException).

3 - **DO NOT FORGET** to close Scanner. It is very important, since it can lead to memory leaks during the execution of a program if you don't close it.

Below you can find the modifications to your code.

#### Full Code

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Bubble {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String prefix;
        int arr[];
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What size would you like your array to be?");
        int arrSize = reader.nextInt();
        arr = new int[arrSize];
        for(int i = 1; i<=arrSize; i++) {

            if((i % 10)==1 && i != 11) {
                prefix = "st";
            }else if((i % 10)==2 && i != 12) {
                prefix = "nd";
            }else if((i % 10)==3 && i != 13) {
                prefix = "rd";
            }else{
                prefix = "th";
            }

            System.out.println("What would you like the "+ i + prefix +" number in the array to be?");
            int arrNum = reader.nextInt();
            arr[i-1] = arrNum;
        }

        reader.close();        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try it thank you so much I literally couldn't find it anywhere ive been searching for hours.